# Prove that the limit of a sequence of polynomials a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sequence-of-function

**Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a convergent sequence of polynomials on D. prove that the limit function f is also a polynomial; or find a counterexample.**

Is this equivalent to "the limit of a sequence of constant functions is also constant" ?

Intuitively, I do not think is true because the limit of each polynomial in the sequence is not a polynomial. Is that logic correct ?

***there are duplicates to this question but those others have the sequence converging uniformly.***

Comment: What is $D{{}}$?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean here by $D$ or by convergence, but I think that this would contradict Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: Sorry but the question I was given D is not  specified, assuming $D \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ for $p \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: What is $D$, what does convergence mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $n$, $f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n z^k/k!$ is a polynomial, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)=\exp(z)$ isn't. In addition the convergence is uniform
in any bounded region of the complex plane.